# Why is my moq db object yielding no results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a moq database with methods that read a json file of serialized entities and deserializes them into a moq dbset. When I set up the dbcontext one table has all the expected results whereas the other table has 0 results. My Json file is properly formatted and verified and has 5 entries.

```
    var airportLocationMoq = GetMockDbSet<Repository.Location>(@"Files/ObjectJson/Airports.json");
    var storageAreaMoq = GetMockDbSet<Repository.StorageArea>(@"Files/ObjectJson/StorageAreas.json");
    var dbContext = new Mock<DbContext>();
    dbContext.Setup(x => x.Locations).Returns(airportLocationMoq.Object);
    dbContext.Setup(x => x.StorageAreas).Returns(storageAreaMoq.Object);

    var airportsFromDb = dbContext.Object.Locations.Where(x => x.Type == 1).ToList();
    var storageAreasFromDb = dbContext.Object.StorageAreas.ToList(); //<-this results in 0 entries however there should be 5.
```

These are the methods that read the json file and deserializes them into moq dbset:

```
public string LoadFile(string path)
        {
            return File.ReadAllText(path);
        }

        public List<T> GetData<T>(string path)
        {
            string json = LoadFile(path);
            var dataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

            return dataList;
        }

        public Mock<DbSet<T>> GetMockDbSet<T>(string path) where T : class
        {
            var data = GetData<T>(path).AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            return mockSet;

        }
```

When I breakpoint into the 'return mockSet' object and open up the Results View the data is present, the list is correctly populated,enter image description here however if I move the cursor away and then go back into it and expand the Results View the data is gone with the 'Enumeration yielded no results'. How is this possible if I've not even moved the breakpoint. I've literaly simply expanded the results view to see the data, moved my mouse cursor away and then drilled back in, in the same instance, and the data is gone. Screenshot provided.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2 - No Results]

Comment: Have you tried changing the slashes in the file paths? i.e. `@"Files\ObjectJson\StorageAreas.json"` => `@"Files/ObjectJson/StorageAreas.json"`

Comment: @RDay Yes I have but to no avail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The actual problem is in the way the mock is initialized.

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
```

This setup returns the same enumerator for every `GetEnumerator` function call. Once items are enumerated, the enumerator yields no more results for subsequent calls.

The setup needs to be modified to use a lambda expression. That way, for every `GetEnumerator` function call a new instance of the enumerator is returned.

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());
```

---

My original assumption about the explicit `IEnumerable<T>` implementation was wrong.

> The `DbSet<T>` class doesn't have any `ToList()` method. To convert
>   the `DbSet<T>`  to a list the `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` method is
>   used.
>
> The interface `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented by the `DbSet<T>` class
>   [explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_6). So I think, you need to setup your `Mock<DbSet<T>>`
>   to return the correct enumerator even for the `IEnumerable<T>`
>   interface.
>
> ```
> mockSet.As<IEnumerable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
> ```

Comment: I've add that also but it doesnt fix the issue. The problem is when I breakpoint and get to the return mockset in the Dbset method the data is present, if I move my mouse courser away and then go back into it the list is empty stating 'enumeration yielded no results' when a second ago the result view was full of entries. How does it contain the data and then remove the data without actually moving off the breakpoint?

Comment: @TheAkhemist Please see updated answer. The problem was in `Mock<DbSet<T>>` setup.

Comment: YES! This did it! You Sir @LukasKabrt are a king! Thank you!

Comment: You are my hero of the day, thanks @Lukas searched hours for this

Comment: <singing>Thank you from the bottom of myyyyyyy, heart</singing>. I don't know why this is true `Once items are enumerated, the enumerator yields no more results for subsequent calls.` but your solution works! I thought I was loosing my mind, now the data is here, and I look again, and it is gone. Thanks!

Comment: The unit test was working with one mocked dbContext, stopeed when I added one more dbContext. This helped me fix the problem. Thanks a bunch.